Node.js server hangs after processing multiple requests with Mocha tests
I'm developing a Node.js server that processes API requests and runs Mocha tests to validate React code. The server works fine for the first 10-12 requests, but then it hangs, keeps loading and stops responding. I suspect there might be a resource or performance issue causing this behavior.
I am using:

Mocha
Express
Babel

When I send requests to this (below) API endpoint, it works fine (as expected) for first 10-12 requests. After that it loads infinitely and does not send response.
I want to make this running smooth as it does for first 10-12 requests.
index.js:
const babel = require("@babel/core");
const express = require("express");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3002;
const cors = require("cors");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const fs = require("fs");
const Mocha = require("mocha");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// const compilerQueue = new Queue("react-compiler");
app.post("/checkQuestion", async (req, res) => {
    const {
        userCode,
        test
    } = req.body;
    const requestId = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");
    const tempDir = `./test-app/src/temp/${requestId}`;

    // Create a temporary directory for the request
    fs.mkdirSync(tempDir);

    // Write the userCode to a file within the temporary directory
    const userCodeFilePath = `${tempDir}/App.js`;
    const testPath = `${tempDir}/App.test.js`;
    let transformedCode = "";
    try {
        transformedCode = babel.transformSync(userCode, {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(200).json({
            err: [{
                err: err.message,
                title: "App is not rendered"
            }],
            pass: [],
        });
    }
    console.log(
        "transformed code.... ",
        transformedCode.code.includes('"use strict";')
    );
    if (!transformedCode.code.includes('"use strict";')) {
        // Send an error response if transformation fails...
        return res.status(200).json({
            err: [{
                err: "App contains syntax errors",
                title: "App contains syntax errors",
            }, ],
            pass: [],
        });
    }

    fs.writeFileSync(userCodeFilePath, transformedCode.code);
    fs.writeFileSync(testPath, test);

    const mocha = new Mocha({
        reporter: "json", // You can use any Mocha reporter you prefer
    });

    // Add test files to Mocha
    mocha.addFile(testPath);

    // Capture test results
    const testResults = {
        err: [],
        pass: []
    };

    // Listen to the test eventss...
    mocha.timeout(100000);
    mocha
        .run({})
        .on("test", function(test) {
            console.log("Test started: " + test.title);
        })
        .on("test end", function(test) {
            console.log("Test done: " + test.title);
        })
        .on("pass", function(test) {
            console.log("Test passed");
            testResults.pass.push({
                title: test.title,
                pass: true,
                duration: test.duration,
                state: test.state,
            });
            // console.clear();
        })
        .on("fail", function(test, err) {
            console.log("Test fail");
            testResults.err.push({
                title: test.title,
                err: test.err.message
            });
            // console.log(test);
            // console.log(err);
        })
        .on("end", function() {
            console.log("All done");
            deleteTempDirectory(tempDir);
            // console.clear();
            console.log(
                "============================",
                testResults,
                "======================="
            );
            return res.json(testResults);
        });
});
// Function to delete temporary directory
function deleteTempDirectory(dirPath) {
    if (fs.existsSync(dirPath)) {
        fs.readdirSync(dirPath).forEach(function(entry) {
            const entryPath = `${dirPath}/${entry}`;
            if (fs.lstatSync(entryPath).isDirectory()) {
                deleteTempDirectory(entryPath);
            } else {
                fs.unlinkSync(entryPath);
            }
        });
        fs.rmdirSync(dirPath);
    }
}

app.listen(3001, () => console.log("APP IS LISTENING ON 3001..."));

package.json:
{
  "name": "react-dom",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.1",
    "chai": "^5.1.0",
    "jsdom": "^24.0.0",
    "mocha": "^10.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "bull": "^4.12.2",
    "bullmq": "^5.5.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mocha-jsdom": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}


Request body (in case you want to run it locally):
{
  "test": "\n\ndescribe('App', () => {\n  let originalInterval;\n\n  before(() => {\n    // Mock setInterval\n    originalInterval = global.setInterval;\n    global.setInterval = (callback, interval) => {\n      callback(); // Immediately invoke the callback\n      return originalInterval(callback, interval);\n    };\n  });\n\n  after(() => {\n    // Restore original setInterval\n    global.setInterval = originalInterval;\n  });\n\n  it('toggles text visibility on button click', async () => {\n     const { JSDOM } = require(\"jsdom\");\nconst dom = new JSDOM(\"<!DOCTYPE html>\");\nglobal.document = dom.window.document;\nglobal.window = dom.window;\nglobal.navigator = dom.window.navigator;\nconst { expect } = await import(\"chai\");\nconst App = require(\"./App\").default;\nconst React = require(\"react\");\nconst { render, fireEvent } = require(\"@testing-library/react\");\nconst { getByText, queryByText } = render(React.createElement(App));\n\n  // Initially, text should not be visible\n    expect(queryByText('Text is Visible')).to.not.exist;\n\n    // Click the button to toggle text visibility\n    const toggleButton = getByText('Toggle Text');\n    fireEvent.click(toggleButton);\n\n    // Text should be visible after clicking the button\n    expect(queryByText('Text is Visible')).to.exist;\n\n    // Click again to hide the text\n    fireEvent.click(toggleButton);\n\n    // Text should not be visible again\n    expect(queryByText('Text is Viible')).to.not.exist;\n const useStateUsage = App.toString().includes('useState');\n expect(useStateUsage).to.be.true;\n });\n});",
  "userCode": "import React, { useState } from 'react';\n\nconst App = () => {\n  const [isTextVisible, setIsTextVisible] = useState(false);\n\n  const toggleText = () => {\n    setIsTextVisible((prev) => !prev);\n  };\n\n  return (\n    <div>\n      <button onClick={toggleText}>Toggle Text</button>\n      {isTextVisible && <p>Text is Visible</p>}\n    </div>\n  );\n};\n\nexport default App;"
}

